# WHERE conditions in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

People, I need a help.

I have the following code:

```
    ...   WHERE res.cod_ordem_producao = pla.cod_ordem_producao -- TO MAKE THE JOIN
  AND (to_char(:codordemproducao)='X' -- INITIAL VALUE FOR THE PARAMETER
       AND to_char(:grau)='X') -- INITIAL VALUE FOR THE PARAMETER
  OR ((to_char(res.cod_ordem_producao) = to_char(:codordemproducao)
       AND to_char(:grau)='X'
       AND res.COD_ESTADO_TUBO IN ('G',
                                   'W')
       AND res.DTH_ENTRADA BETWEEN :dth_inicio AND :dth_final )
      OR (to_char(pla.dsc_aco) = to_char(:grau)
          AND to_char(:codordemproducao)='X'
          AND res.COD_ESTADO_TUBO IN ('G',
                                      'W')
          AND res.DTH_ENTRADA BETWEEN :dth_inicio AND :dth_final ))
ORDER BY res.DTH_ENTRADA
```

We have 3 parameter here: DATE, CODORDEM, GRAU. The user can enter with;

1. ONLY the 'date' (without 'GRAU' and 'CODORDEM')
2. The 'date' AND the 'grau' (without 'CODORDEM')
3. The 'date' AND the 'codordem' (without 'grau')

Where is my mistake in the code?

My actual code does:
1 - the user can enter with date + grau + codordem
2 - the user can enter with date + grau

Comment: One error is "making the join" using a condition in the `WHERE` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax with `ON` clauses.

Comment: What makes you think there is a mistake in the first place?

Comment: You haven't explained why you think there is a mistake at all - we don't know what this code is expected to do or what it's actually doing (though we can guess of course), or how it's being called. (And you have four parameters, not three...) The `to_char()` calls look odd, incidentally.

Comment: You are missing brackets to encapsulate the initial OR - I believe you want the join condition to always be true, and then either the first or second branches of the "actual" predicates to be true. If you used the ANSI join syntax, you wouldn't need an extra layer of brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move join condition to join clause. Add criterium for dates always. Then check if both of remaining parameters are null or only one of them and second is met.

```
...
from res
join pla on res.cod_ordem_producao = pla.cod_ordem_producao
where res.dth_entrada between :dth_inicio and :dth_final
  and 
    (
      (:codordemproducao is null and :grau is null)
      or (
           (
             (:codordemproducao is null and to_char(pla.dsc_aco) = to_char(:grau))
             or 
             (:grau is null and to_char(res.cod_ordem_producao) = to_char(:codordemproducao))
           )
           and res.cod_estado_tubo in ('G', 'W')
         )
    )
```

Replace `:parameter is null` with `to_char(:parameter) = 'X'` if they are sent as `X`s. As I understood situation where you provide dates and both remaining parameters is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that user can enter one of three parametrs. So you need to add NVL to every condition, where You have parameter for example:

```
res.DTH_ENTRADA BETWEEN :dth_inicio AND :dth_final
```

TO

```
res.DTH_ENTRADA BETWEEN NVL(:dth_inicio,res.DTH_ENTRADA) AND NVL(res.DTH_ENTRADA,:dth_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the conditions are wrong combined. The first condition is always present (date condition) and all others conditions could be combined by OR operator.

```
...   WHERE
res.cod_ordem_producao = pla.cod_ordem_producao 
AND res.DTH_ENTRADA BETWEEN :dth_inicio AND :dth_final
AND 
(
          (to_char(:codordemproducao)='X' AND to_char(:grau)='X') 
          OR 
          (to_char(res.cod_ordem_producao) = to_char(:codordemproducao) AND to_char(:grau)='X' AND res.COD_ESTADO_TUBO IN ('G', 'W'))
          OR 
          (to_char(pla.dsc_aco) = to_char(:grau) AND to_char(:codordemproducao)='X'  AND res.COD_ESTADO_TUBO IN ('G','W'))
)
ORDER BY res.DTH_ENTRADA
```